# Powershell command to remove "#" (in folder and subfolders)

Tags: batch, powershell

according to topic:

[Batch script to remove # from a file name (only in a specific directory)](https://superuser.com/questions/668290/batch-script-to-remove-from-a-file-name-only-in-a-specific-directory/1249906?noredirect=1#comment1835196_1249906)

is there a quick way to extend powershell command (from @Peter Hahndorf answer) to make it work on subfolders to?
Or how it could be done? (using powershell).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes. just add the `-recursive` switch to `Get-Childitem`

Comment: you can see this answer in stackoverflow from @Ravi Thapliyal : [Replace or delete certain characters from filenames of all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636996/replace-or-delete-certain-characters-from-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch solution, change the path to fit your environment.

```
@Echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/S "X:\path\to\start\*#*" 2^>Nul') do (
    set "fn=%%~nxA"
    Call ren "%%A" "%%fn:#=%%"
)
```

A PowerShell one liner doesn't need a ForEach as `Rename-Item` accepts piped input:

```
Get-ChildItem '*#*' -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -Replace '#'}
```